# Copy paste loop vba - overwrites the current cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am on the process if creating vba that would copy and paste from one sheet to another.

Here is the loop:

```
j = Archive.Range("A12", Archive.Range("A12").End(xlToRight).Columns.Count --> count of sheet 2
```

(Reference is the sheet 1: If any column from row 15 is 1 then it will copy to Archive)

```
For i = k to 2 Step -1

If Reference.Cells(15, i). Value = 1 Then Reference.Columns(i).Copy
Archive.Cells(1, 1 + j).PasteSpecial
End If
Next i
```

The macro is working but the problem on the loop is that it only copy and paste on the next available cell and does not proceed to the next cell if another record from cell 15 is equals to 1. I want it to continuously copy paste the data to the next available column.

Comment: You need to update `j` *inside* the loop. `1 + j` doesn't change the value of `j`. `j = j + 1` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `j` inside the loop.

If `j` originally equals 15, for example, then `1 + j` will equal 16 for each iteration of the loop. `1 + j` never changes the value of `j`.

Try instead:

```
If Reference.Cells(15, i). Value = 1 Then 
    j = j + 1  ' update j
    Reference.Columns(i).Copy
    Archive.Cells(1, j).PasteSpecial
End If
```